# filter filenames in logql (grafana), extracted from multiple subfolders

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I am building a dashboard in grafana, and previously, my queries to get the logs were:

`{filename=~"/var/logs/tfc/local/reportserver+.+"}`

This was to get all rotated files from the reportserver logs.
Now there may be other servers sending their logs into `/var/logs/tfc/` but in different subfolders. So I tried this new filter, to get all reportserver logs from all subdirectories:

`{filename=~"/var/logs/tfc/**/reportserver+.+"}`
But this is not working. How can I modi fy the query to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex selector `=~` uses regexes, but you have some strange mix of regex and ant-style globs.

Based on your description I believe you need this query:

```
{filename=~"/var/logs/tfc/.+/reportserver.+"}
```

Comment: It works!!! I ve been losing sleep over this!